# Using curly braces in QML input mask

Tags: qt, qml, curly-braces, input-mask

I have a QML line edit, and am trying to use the input mask to ensure a valid UID is entered.  My input mask is set like this:

```
inputMask: ">\\{NNNNNNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNNNNNNNNNN\\}"
```

and my text property is set to: "{49f93de5-1da6-4e3a-a2e4-64795dc89ebb}"

When I run my program the curly braces are missing from the screen's edit field (but the hyphens are present and character masks are correctly applied).  How can I show the { and } ?  I assumed escaping them in the mask was all that was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem relates to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop)

**Edited:** wrapping the input string in `qsTr()` allows the curly braces to show in the input text.

in QML I use TextInput and it works :

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextInput {
        id: textInput
        x: 116
        y: 94
        width: 237
        height: 53
        text: qsTr("{49f93de5-1da6-4e3a-a2e4-64795dc89ebb}")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        inputMask: ">\\{NNNNNNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNNNNNNNNNN\\}"
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what you are doing differently!  What is it that allows the curly braces to appear in your example?

Comment: Ok I found it!  For some reason wrapping the input string in qStr() allows the curly braces to show in the input text.  I don't really understand why this matters however.  If you know could you add that to your answer?  (I'm sure it will help others)

Comment: @TSG , yes sure . Thanks